# Setup failed when installing Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Sorry for dupplicate.

I installed VS 2013 with Update 3 on disk E. By using a software, I merged disk D and E to one partition. And the data was lost.

But, i restarted my pc, i could still uninstalled some software. VS 2013 is not one of them.

VS said that it needs a source to complete. I can't provide it. Nothing in disk E, it includes VS 2013 source.

After that. I linked to visualstudio.com and download new version. It's VS 2013 with Update 4.
I downloaded iso file, and burned to my usb.

When running as administrator, it shows me 1 error and many warning. Like this:

```
 The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.
```

The installer was stopped.

I had referenced many relate, some ideas are:

-- Uninstall VS 2013 Update 3. Restart and try to install VS Update 4. I can't do this.

-- Read this link: [Visual Studio 2013 Setup: common issues and workarounds](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2899270). I read and... still didn't see any solution to solve my trouble. The installer didn't tell me "Why" or give me any error code about the problem.

So, my problem is:

I have VS 2013 with Update 3 on my system, and the source was lost. I can't uninstall it.
I want to install new VS 2013 with Update 4 within Update 3. But I don't know how to do that.

Can you give me any solution?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is meant by *"I want to install new VS 2013 with Update 4 within Update 3"*. However, I can provide you the steps to uninstall an update of VS 2013.

Go to **Control Panel->Programs->Programs and Features**.
Now on the left you will see **View installed updates** on the top left of the side bar as shown below.

[image]

Now under VS 2013, you should be able to see all the updates. Right click an update and click Uninstall. 
[image]

Good Luck!